# Generics in Java-Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, generics, primitive

I want to code a little library for myself. Here is some code which I want to provide in it.

```
public class ThreadUtils {    
    private static String result;   
    public static Void runInBackground(final Callable<Void> func) {    
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    func.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();    
        return null;
    }  
    public static String runInBackground(final Callable<String> func) {    
        result = "";    
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    result = func.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();    
        return result;
    }    
}
```

I'm quite surprised that my IDE says that it won't work, because of a duplicate declaration. Why is that, normally it recognizes that the parameter are different, but it won't? **How can it be made that runInBackground is able to return different primitive types?**

Comment: nope... "Void"... "void" won't be accepted as an valid parameter.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils +1, thank you so much.

Comment: nice, and how to use this information?

Comment: Is this the only two cases or are you going to end up with a lot of these?

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel, and badly. For example, your second method will not compile, and even if it did, it would **always** return an empty string. You can't return a synchronous result from a method whose point is to copute a result asynchronously. Use an ExecutorService and its submit() method. Don't ignore exceptions as you're doing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: @JB Nizet your right, actually I'm testing (think of it as "playing with java") - this code is not for production right now... But e.printStackTrace() is ignoring an exception??

Comment: Yes: the caller of the asynchronous task has no way to know if the computation went good or bad, and how/why it went bad. And no one reads what is printed on the console.

Comment: I do. :) Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of type erasure, generics in Java are not available at run-time. This means that you have two methods with the same name and same argument types, therefore Java cannot choose which one to use.

You will have to give your methods different names:

```
public static Void calculateVoidInBackground(final Callable<Void> func) {
    ...
}    
public static String calculateStringInBackground(final Callable<String> func) {
    ...
}
```

To answer your second question: primitive types cannot be used as generic parameters. You can however use the wrapper classes (such as `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`) provided by Java. Because of auto-boxing primitive types are automatically converted to instances of the wrapper classes and vice versa:

```
public static int calculateIntInBackground(final Callable<Integer> func) {
    ...
}
```